# Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, mkannotation

I have a MapViewController for presenting annotations on map. It contains an 
object of type MapPresentable.

```
protocol MapPresentable {
    associatedtype AnnotationElement: MKAnnotation
    var annotations: [AnnotationElement] { get }
}

class MapViewController<M: MapPresentable>: UIViewController {
    var mapPresentable: M!
}
```

MapViewController can also present route on map in case `mapPresentable` conforms to RoutePresentable protocol.

```
protocol RoutePresentable: MapPresentable {
    var getRouteLocations: [CLLocation] { get }
}
```

But when checking made inside `MapViewController`

```
if let routePresentable = mapPresentable as? RoutePresentable {
    showRoute(routePresentable.getRouteLocations)
}
```

I got this Error:

```
Protocol 'RoutePresentable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Updated

Sorry, I make mistakes. But there is no way to cast a protocol with `associated type`.

Hope this will help.

As i known the `routePresentable.getRouteLocations` has nothing to do with protocol `MapPresentable`.

So you can divide `RoutePresentable` to two protocol:

```
protocol MapPresentable {
    associatedtype AnnotationElement: MKAnnotation
    var annotations: [AnnotationElement] { get }
}

class MapViewController<M: MapPresentable>: UIViewController {
    var mapPresentable: M!

}

protocol RoutePresentable: MapPresentable, CanGetRouteLocations {}

protocol CanGetRouteLocations {
    var getRouteLocations: [CLLocation] { get }
}


if let routePresentable = mapPresentable as? CanGetRouteLocations {
    showRoute(routePresentable.getRouteLocations)
}
```

## Original

Because `routePresentable.annotations`'s Type is unprovided,

You can just remove `associatedtype AnnotationElement: MKAnnotation`.

Or user generic struct instead:

```
struct MapPresentable<AnnotationElement: MKAnnotation> {
    var annotations: [AnnotationElement] = []
}

struct RoutePresentable<AnnotationElement: MKAnnotation> {
    var mapPresentable: MapPresentable<AnnotationElement>
    var getRouteLocations: [CLLocation] = []
}

class MapViewController<AnnotationElement: MKAnnotation>: UIViewController {

    var mapPresentable: MapPresentable<AnnotationElement>!

}

if let routePresentable = mapPresentable as? RoutePresentable<MKAnnotation> {
    showRoute(routePresentable.getRouteLocations)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I didn't understand you generic solution. MapPresentable & RoutePresentable must be protocols (there are actual types conforming to it). And how exactly cast statement will work? In this case MapPresentable & RoutePresentable are different structs..

Comment: Great! Your update helped solve the casting issue! Thank you!